How to Run MIPS Assembly natively in 2024/ Loongarch MIPS compatability
Is it possibly to run MIPS III without emulation in 2024? Should I look for used hardware or are there current architectures that support backwards compatibility; specifically could Loongarch based systems do this?
I have tried looking for some older workstations that have NEC processors and such. The other threads that I looked through for this issue mentioned trying to use Loongson processors for this purpose, but they are from 2012 (Loongson CPU and MIPS Assembly?). From what I understand, Loongson has since moved towards their own ISA called Loongarch that still has a lot of similarities to MIPS. I have been considering ordering a cheap development board off of AliExpress (2K1000LA development board Loongarch development board), but I wanted to see if there were any resources regarding Loongarch MIPS compatibility.
I am very new to this area, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check what is on-topic here (asking for hardware recommendations is not -- maybe it is not on-topic anywhere on stackexchange, as answers tend to get outdated after a while).
